# Join 2 different entities from 2 different models into a single Linq to Entities query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a default Entity Framework model that holds all of my default tables for my product, and that all customers share in common. However, on some customers, I have some custom tables that exist for only that customer, but they relate to the default product's tables. I have a second Entity Framework model to hold these custom tables.
My question is how can I make a Linq to Entities query using Join so I can relate the entities from my default model to the tables on my custom model? I don't mind not having the Navigation properties from the custom entity to the entities on the default model; I just need a way to query both models in a single query.
Below is the code:

```
  using (ProductEntities oProductDB = new ProductEntities())
  {
    using (ProductEntitiesCustom oProductCustomDB = new ProductEntitiesCustom())
    {
      var oConsulta = oProductCustomDB.CTBLCustoms
                .Where(CTBLCustoms => CTBLCustoms.IDWOHD >= 12)
                .Join(oProductDB.TBLResources,
                     CTBLCustoms => new
                       {
                         CTBLCustoms.IDResource
                       },
                     TBLResources => new
                       {
                         TBLResources.IDResource
                       },
                    (CTBLCustoms, TBLResources) => new
                       {
                         IDCustom = CTBLCustoms.IDCustom,
                         Descricao = CTBLCustoms.Descricao,
                         IDWOHD = CTBLCustoms.IDWOHD,
                         IDResource = CTBLCustoms.IDResource,
                         ResourceCode = TBLResources.Code
                       });

      gvwDados.DataSource = oConsulta;
    }
  }
```

I get a `The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts` error.
**EDIT** 
Could I merge the 2 `ObjectContext` into a third, and then run the Linq query?
Tks
**EDIT**
Below is the code that worked, using the AsEnumerable() proposed solution:

```
  using (ProductEntities oProductDB = new ProductEntities())
  {
    using (ProductEntitiesCustom oProductCustomDB = new ProductEntitiesCustom())
    {
      var oConsulta = (oProductCustomDB.CTBLCustoms.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(CTBLCustoms => CTBLCustoms.IDWOHD >= 12)
                .Join(oProductDB.TBLResources,
                     CTBLCustoms => new
                       {
                         CTBLCustoms.IDResource
                       },
                     TBLResources => new
                       {
                         TBLResources.IDResource
                       },
                    (CTBLCustoms, TBLResources) => new
                       {
                         IDCustom = CTBLCustoms.IDCustom,
                         Descricao = CTBLCustoms.Descricao,
                         IDWOHD = CTBLCustoms.IDWOHD,
                         IDResource = CTBLCustoms.IDResource,
                         ResourceCode = TBLResources.Code
                       })).ToList();

      gvwDados.DataSource = oConsulta;
    }
  }
```

I added the `AsEnumerable()` as suggested, but I had to add the `ToList()` at the end so I could databind it to the DataGridView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this in L2E. You could bring this into object space with `AsEnumerable()`, and it would work, but possibly be inefficient.

Merging the ObjectContexts is possible, and would work, but would need to be done manually.

Comment: Tks. Do you have some links so that I can get more information about the methods you suggested? Tks so much